# Ignore special characters from a list excluding the mentioned characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I had been using regex to ignore special characters from my list. But now I want to ignore special character excluding a few special characters mentioned by the user.

The code that I am currently using to remove special character is :

```
final_list=[re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', _)for _ in a]
```

This works fine when I want to remove all the special characters in my list.

**Input:**

```
["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]
```

**output:**

```
['on3', 'two', 'three']
```

But what my expectation is if I give ignore special characters except `$#%`

**Input:**

```
["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]
```

**output:**

```
['on3', 'two#', 'thre%e']
```

This is my expected output

`$#%` is just for example. The user can mention any special character and I need the code to not remove the special character mentioned by the user but remove all other special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add those charecters to the regex as

```
[re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9$#%]+', '', _)for _ in a]
                    ^^^
```

as @DYZ mentioned, you could also use **`'[^\w$#%]+'`** regex

```
[re.sub('[^\w$#%]+', '', _)for _ in a]
```

---

### UPDATE-1

```
import re
a = ["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]
special_char_to_be_removed = "%" # here you can change the values
regex = '[^\w{your_regex}]+'.format(your_regex=special_char_to_be_removed)
[re.sub(regex, '', _)for _ in a]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

This works fine when $#% should always be ignored but this changes depending on the requirement it may be ^&* or !@.
The user will change the special character to be avoided depending on his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the list of characters to the list.

```
import re

a = ["on@3", "two$", "thre%e"]

final_list = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\$#%]+', '', _) for _ in a]

print final_list
```

outputs

```
['on3', 'two$', 'thre%e']
```

`$` has a meaning in regular expressions so you need to escape it with a `\`

If you want to take user input, just use

```
import re

a = ["on@3", "two$", "thre%e"]

except_special_chars = input('Exceptions:')

final_list = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9'+str(except_special_chars)+']+', '', _) for _ in a]

print final_list
```

then the user input the special characters between quotes `'` and with an escaping `\` if necessary.

Comment: There is no need to call `str`.